# Does An only come before apple

Tags: articles, determiners

In some class, I had in elementary we learned

> I ate **an** apple.
>
> I drove **a** car.

*An* only comes with *apple* everything other object takes *A*.

Later on, I found this on google.

> He is **an** education instructor.

We were in first grade and he was trying to make it simple.

What I meant is at some age you learn something. Later on, you learn new things.

That makes that first thing you learned a bit incorrect.

Was the teacher tricking us??

Comment: Please look up the use of **determiners** in English: a/an. Thanks.

Comment: Your teacher actually said, *'An' is only before 'apple'*? That's just so wrong it's bizarre.  Either you misunderstood, or yes, your teacher was deliberately misleading you.   This is very basic English grammar.  See https://www.englishpage.com/articles/a-vs-an.htm

Comment: Perhaps **apple** was the only word in a particular list which would take "an".

Comment: yes at that time but he did say none in all English you learning He properly meant at that year xD

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on obvious misinformation. At best, more explanation is necessary.

Comment: related:  [when should I use a vs an](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152/when-should-i-use-a-vs-an)

Comment: Sometimes we don't understand what we learned in the first place. We think we are being taught a universal truth but instead we are being taught a general guideline that has exceptions. Or maybe we mishear or misinterpret what a teacher is saying. Or a teacher might be perpetuating a myth. There's no way to sure what happened in this case, but we should always remember that learning is a process – an ongoing process.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In English, we use *a* before words that sound like they begin with consonants.

> We saw *a* **b**ook on the table.
>
> There is *a* **s**pider on your shoulder.

Some words begin with vowels, but when pronounced phonetically, sound like they start with a consonant:

> The main character is *a* **u**nicorn. *(YOU-ni-corn)*
>
> The third number is *a* **o**ne. *(WUHN)*

---

We use *an* before words that sound like they begin with vowels.

> I have *an* **o**ld clock in my living room.
>
> *An* **a**pple fell out of the tree.

Some words begin with consonants, but when pronounced phonetically, sound like they begin with vowels:

> We only have *an* **h**our until the train comes. *(OW-ur)*
>
> The second letter is *an* **F**. *(EFF)*

---

Was your teacher tricking you? Maybe. It depends on context. If the only word that you learned that used *an* was *apple*, then it isn't as bad, because they are trying to prevent confusion. If they stated that out of all words in the English language, the only word that used *an* was *apple*, that is definitely wrong and misleading.

Comment: For completeness, you might want to include the weird (not-silent) 'h' examples that get 'an' as discussed on the [sister site](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/629/when-should-i-use-a-versus-an-in-front-of-a-word-beginning-with-the-letter-h).

Answer (score 2):

**an** is used when the word which follows starts with a *vowel sound*, else **a** is used.

#### For example:

> Since it's raining, I will need *an* umbrella; hopefully the rain will stop in *an* hour.

> I thought I saw *a* unicorn, but I know it's *an* imaginary creature.

In the first example, notice that *an* is used even though `hour` starts with a consonant - this is because the pronunciation of the word `hour` starts with a vowel *sound*; similarly, in the second example, *a* precedes the word `unicorn` since the pronunciation of this word starts with a consonant sound.